# Estimation parameters using GEKKO (a second-order differential equation)

Tags: python, gekko

I am using a second-order parallel model:

[image]

It has four parameters (initial values Cf0 and Cs0, kf and ks) to be estimated using GEKKO and six experiments. However I am not achieving a good fit, only experiments 1 and 4 are moving near the experiment data. Maybe I have some error in the code. Despite this, any guide-lines or link to get more information on controlling boundaries and the estimation method would be very helpful.

[image]

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math as math
import pandas as pd

tm1 = [0, 0.0667,0.5,1,4]
mca1 = [5.68, 3.48, 3.24, 3.36, 2.96]

tm2 = [0, 0.08333,0.5,1,4.25]
mca2 = [5.68, 4.20, 4.04, 4.00, 3.76]

tm3 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.33]
mca3 = [5.68, 4.64, 4.52, 4.56, 4.24]

tm4 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.0833]
mca4 =[18.90,15.4,14.3,15.10,13.50]

tm5 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.5]
mca5 =[18.90, 15.5, 16.30, 16, 14.70]

tm6 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.6667]
mca6 = [18.90, 15.8, 11.70,15.5,12]

df1=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm1,'x1':mca1})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm2,'x2':mca2})
df3=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm3,'x3':mca3})
df4=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm4,'x4':mca4})
df5=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm5,'x5':mca5})
df6=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm6,'x6':mca6})
df1.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df3.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df4.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df5.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df6.set_index('time',inplace=True)
#simulation time points
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.linspace(0,5,101)})
dfx.set_index('time',inplace=True)
#merge dataframes
dfxx=dfx.join(df1,how='outer')
dfxxx=dfxx.join(df2,how='outer')
dfxxxx=dfxxx.join(df3,how='outer')
dfxxxxx=dfxxxx.join(df4,how='outer')
dfxxxxxx=dfxxxxx.join(df5,how='outer')
df=dfxxxxxx.join(df6,how='outer')
# get True (1) or False (0) for measurement
df['meas1']=(df['x1'].values==df['x1'].values).astype(int)
df['meas2']=(df['x2'].values==df['x2'].values).astype(int)
df['meas3']=(df['x3'].values==df['x3'].values).astype(int)
df['meas4']=(df['x4'].values==df['x4'].values).astype(int)
df['meas5']=(df['x5'].values==df['x5'].values).astype(int)
df['meas6']=(df['x6'].values==df['x6'].values).astype(int)
#replace NaN with zeros
df0=df.fillna(value=0)

m = GEKKO()
m.time = df0.index.values

meas1 = m.Param(df0['meas1'].values)
meas2 = m.Param(df0['meas2'].values)
meas3 = m.Param(df0['meas3'].values)
meas4 = m.Param(df0['meas4'].values)
meas5 = m.Param(df0['meas5'].values)
meas6 = m.Param(df0['meas6'].values)

#adjustable Parameters
cnf01=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10) 
cns01=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10) 
kf=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10) 
ks=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10) 

cnf02=m.FV(value=cnf01*0.5,lb=cnf01*0.5, ub=cnf01*0.5)
cns02=m.FV(value=cns01*0.5,lb=cns01*0.5, ub=cns01*0.5)
cnf03=m.FV(value=cnf01*0.25,lb=cnf01*0.25, ub=cnf01*0.25)
cns03=m.FV(value=cns01*0.25,lb=cns01*0.25, ub=cns01*0.25)
cnf04=m.FV(value=cnf01,lb=cnf01, ub=cnf01)
cns04=m.FV(value=cns01,lb=cns01, ub=cns01)
cnf05=m.FV(value=cnf01*0.5,lb=cnf01*0.5, ub=cnf01*0.5)
cns05=m.FV(value=cns01*0.5,lb=cns01*0.5, ub=cns01*0.5)
cnf06=m.FV(value=cnf01*0.25,lb=cnf01*0.25, ub=cnf01*0.25)
cns06=m.FV(value=cns01*0.25,lb=cns01*0.25, ub=cns01*0.25)

#Variables
c1 = m.Var(value=mca1[0])
c2 = m.Var(value=mca2[0])
c3 = m.Var(value=mca3[0])
c4 = m.Var(value=mca4[0])
c5 = m.Var(value=mca5[0])
c6 = m.Var(value=mca6[0])
cm1 = m.Param(df0['x1'].values)
cm2 = m.Param(df0['x2'].values)
cm3 = m.Param(df0['x3'].values)
cm4 = m.Param(df0['x4'].values)
cm5 = m.Param(df0['x5'].values)
cm6 = m.Param(df0['x6'].values)

m.Minimize((meas1*(c1-cm1)**2)+(meas2*(c2-cm2)**2)+(meas3*(c3-cm3)**2)+(meas4*(c4-cm4)**2)+(meas5*(c5-cm5)**2)+(meas6*(c6-cm6)**2))

cnf1=m.Var(value=cnf01)
cns1=m.Var(value=cns01)
cnf2=m.Var(value=cnf02)
cns2=m.Var(value=cns02)
cnf3=m.Var(value=cnf03)
cns3=m.Var(value=cns03)
cnf4=m.Var(value=cnf04)
cns4=m.Var(value=cns04)
cnf5=m.Var(value=cnf05)
cns5=m.Var(value=cns05)
cnf6=m.Var(value=cnf06)
cns6=m.Var(value=cns06)

#Equations
t = m.Param(value=m.time)

m.Equation(cnf1.dt()==-kf*c1*cnf1)
m.Equation(cns1.dt()==-ks*c1*cns1)
m.Equation(c1.dt()==cnf1.dt()+cns1.dt())

m.Equation(cnf2.dt()==-kf*c2*cnf2)
m.Equation(cns2.dt()==-ks*c2*cns2)
m.Equation(c2.dt()==cnf2.dt()+cns2.dt())

m.Equation(cnf3.dt()==-kf*c3*cnf3)
m.Equation(cns3.dt()==-ks*c3*cns3)
m.Equation(c3.dt()==cnf3.dt()+cns3.dt())

m.Equation(cnf4.dt()==-kf*c4*cnf4)
m.Equation(cns4.dt()==-ks*c4*cns4)
m.Equation(c4.dt()==cnf4.dt()+cns4.dt())

m.Equation(cnf5.dt()==-kf*c5*cnf5)
m.Equation(cns5.dt()==-ks*c5*cns5)
m.Equation(c5.dt()==cnf5.dt()+cns5.dt())

m.Equation(cnf6.dt()==-kf*c6*cnf6)
m.Equation(cns6.dt()==-ks*c6*cns6)
m.Equation(c6.dt()==cnf6.dt()+cns6.dt())

m.Equation(ks>0)
m.Equation(kf>0)
m.Equation(cnf01>0)
m.Equation(cns01>0)

#Options
m.options.SOLVER = 3 #IPOPT solver
m.options.IMODE = 5 #Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation = MHE
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 #absolute error
m.options.NODES = 3 #collocation nodes (2,5)
m.solve(disp=True)

if True:
    kf.STATUS=1
    ks.STATUS=1
    cnf01.STATUS=1
    cns01.STATUS=1
    cnf02.STATUS=1
    cns02.STATUS=1
    cnf03.STATUS=1
    cns03.STATUS=1
    cnf04.STATUS=1
    cns04.STATUS=1
    cnf05.STATUS=1
    cns05.STATUS=1
    cnf06.STATUS=1
    cns06.STATUS=1

print('Final SSE Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))

print('Solution')
print('cnf01 = ' + str(cnf01.value[0]))
print('cns01 = ' + str(cns01.value[0]))
print('kf = ' + str(kf.value[0]))
print('ks = ' + str(ks.value[0]))
print('cns02 = '+ str(cns02.value[0]))
print('cnf02 = '+ str(cnf02.value[0]))
print('cns03 = '+ str(cns03.value[0]))
print('cnf03 = '+ str(cnf03.value[0]))
print('cns04 = '+ str(cns04.value[0]))
print('cnf04 = '+ str(cnf04.value[0]))
print('cns05 = '+ str(cns05.value[0]))
print('cnf05 = '+ str(cnf05.value[0]))
print('cns06 = '+ str(cns06.value[0]))
print('cnf06 = '+ str(cnf06.value[0]))

plt.figure(1,figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(m.time,c1.value,'b',label='Predicted c1')
plt.plot(m.time,c2.value,'r',label='Predicted c2')
plt.plot(m.time,c3.value,'g',label='Predicted c3')
plt.plot(m.time,c4.value,'b',label='Predicted c4')
plt.plot(m.time,c5.value,'r',label='Predicted c5')
plt.plot(m.time,c6.value,'g',label='Predicted c6')
plt.plot(tm1,mca1,'bo',label='Meas c1')
plt.plot(tm2,mca2,'ro',label='Meas c2')
plt.plot(tm3,mca3,'go',label='Meas c3')
plt.plot(tm4,mca4,'bo',label='Meas c4')
plt.plot(tm5,mca5,'ro',label='Meas c5')
plt.plot(tm6,mca6,'go',label='Meas c6')
plt.xlabel('time (h)')
plt.ylabel('Concentration (mg/L)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `STATUS=1` needs to be before the `m.solve()` to make `kf` and `ks` adjustable by the solver.

```py
if True:
    kf.STATUS=1
    ks.STATUS=1
```

The additional inequality constraint aren't needed because they already have lower bounds set elsewhere.

```py
m.Equation(ks>0)
m.Equation(kf>0)
m.Equation(cnf01>0)
m.Equation(cns01>0)
```

The initial conditions are calculated by including `fixed_initial=False`.

```py
cnf1=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cns1=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cnf2=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cns2=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cnf3=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cns3=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cnf4=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cns4=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cnf5=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cns5=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cnf6=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cns6=m.Var(value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
```

One way to shorten the model is to use Arrays.

```py
cnf1,cnf2,cnf3,cnf4,cnf5,cnf6 = m.Array(m.Var,6,\
            value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False
cns1,cns2,cns3,cns4,cns5,cns6 = m.Array(m.Var,6,\
            value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False
```

The IPOPT solver fails to converge after 250 iterations. Switching to the APOPT solver gives a successful solution.

```py
m.options.SOLVER=1
```

[image: solution]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math as math
import pandas as pd

tm1 = [0, 0.0667,0.5,1,4]
mca1 = [5.68, 3.48, 3.24, 3.36, 2.96]

tm2 = [0, 0.08333,0.5,1,4.25]
mca2 = [5.68, 4.20, 4.04, 4.00, 3.76]

tm3 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.33]
mca3 = [5.68, 4.64, 4.52, 4.56, 4.24]

tm4 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.0833]
mca4 =[18.90,15.4,14.3,15.10,13.50]

tm5 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.5]
mca5 =[18.90, 15.5, 16.30, 16, 14.70]

tm6 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.6667]
mca6 = [18.90, 15.8, 11.70,15.5,12]

df1=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm1,'x1':mca1})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm2,'x2':mca2})
df3=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm3,'x3':mca3})
df4=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm4,'x4':mca4})
df5=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm5,'x5':mca5})
df6=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm6,'x6':mca6})
df1.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df3.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df4.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df5.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df6.set_index('time',inplace=True)
#simulation time points
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.linspace(0,5,101)})
dfx.set_index('time',inplace=True)
#merge dataframes
dfxx=dfx.join(df1,how='outer')
dfxxx=dfxx.join(df2,how='outer')
dfxxxx=dfxxx.join(df3,how='outer')
dfxxxxx=dfxxxx.join(df4,how='outer')
dfxxxxxx=dfxxxxx.join(df5,how='outer')
df=dfxxxxxx.join(df6,how='outer')
# get True (1) or False (0) for measurement
df['meas1']=(df['x1'].values==df['x1'].values).astype(int)
df['meas2']=(df['x2'].values==df['x2'].values).astype(int)
df['meas3']=(df['x3'].values==df['x3'].values).astype(int)
df['meas4']=(df['x4'].values==df['x4'].values).astype(int)
df['meas5']=(df['x5'].values==df['x5'].values).astype(int)
df['meas6']=(df['x6'].values==df['x6'].values).astype(int)
#replace NaN with zeros
df0=df.fillna(value=0)

m = GEKKO()
m.time = df0.index.values

meas1 = m.Param(df0['meas1'].values)
meas2 = m.Param(df0['meas2'].values)
meas3 = m.Param(df0['meas3'].values)
meas4 = m.Param(df0['meas4'].values)
meas5 = m.Param(df0['meas5'].values)
meas6 = m.Param(df0['meas6'].values)

#adjustable Parameters
kf=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10) 
ks=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10) 

#Variables
c1 = m.Var(value=mca1[0])
c2 = m.Var(value=mca2[0])
c3 = m.Var(value=mca3[0])
c4 = m.Var(value=mca4[0])
c5 = m.Var(value=mca5[0])
c6 = m.Var(value=mca6[0])
cm1 = m.Param(df0['x1'].values)
cm2 = m.Param(df0['x2'].values)
cm3 = m.Param(df0['x3'].values)
cm4 = m.Param(df0['x4'].values)
cm5 = m.Param(df0['x5'].values)
cm6 = m.Param(df0['x6'].values)

m.Minimize((meas1*(c1-cm1)**2)+(meas2*(c2-cm2)**2)\
          +(meas3*(c3-cm3)**2)+(meas4*(c4-cm4)**2)\
          +(meas5*(c5-cm5)**2)+(meas6*(c6-cm6)**2))

cnf1,cnf2,cnf3,cnf4,cnf5,cnf6 = m.Array(m.Var,6,\
            value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)
cns1,cns2,cns3,cns4,cns5,cns6 = m.Array(m.Var,6,\
            value=1.3,lb=0.0,ub=10,fixed_initial=False)

#Equations
t = m.Param(value=m.time)

m.Equation(cnf1.dt()==-kf*c1*cnf1)
m.Equation(cns1.dt()==-ks*c1*cns1)
m.Equation(c1.dt()==cnf1.dt()+cns1.dt())

m.Equation(cnf2.dt()==-kf*c2*cnf2)
m.Equation(cns2.dt()==-ks*c2*cns2)
m.Equation(c2.dt()==cnf2.dt()+cns2.dt())

m.Equation(cnf3.dt()==-kf*c3*cnf3)
m.Equation(cns3.dt()==-ks*c3*cns3)
m.Equation(c3.dt()==cnf3.dt()+cns3.dt())

m.Equation(cnf4.dt()==-kf*c4*cnf4)
m.Equation(cns4.dt()==-ks*c4*cns4)
m.Equation(c4.dt()==cnf4.dt()+cns4.dt())

m.Equation(cnf5.dt()==-kf*c5*cnf5)
m.Equation(cns5.dt()==-ks*c5*cns5)
m.Equation(c5.dt()==cnf5.dt()+cns5.dt())

m.Equation(cnf6.dt()==-kf*c6*cnf6)
m.Equation(cns6.dt()==-ks*c6*cns6)
m.Equation(c6.dt()==cnf6.dt()+cns6.dt())

if True:
    kf.STATUS=1
    ks.STATUS=1

#Options
m.options.SOLVER = 1 #IPOPT solver
m.options.IMODE = 5 #Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation = MHE
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 #absolute error
m.options.NODES = 3 #collocation nodes (2,5)
m.solve(disp=True)

print('Final SSE Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))

print('Solution')
print('kf = ' + str(kf.value[0]))
print('ks = ' + str(ks.value[0]))

if True:
    print('cnf01 = ' + str(cnf1.value[0]))
    print('cns01 = ' + str(cns1.value[0]))
    print('cns02 = '+ str(cns2.value[0]))
    print('cnf02 = '+ str(cnf2.value[0]))
    print('cns03 = '+ str(cns3.value[0]))
    print('cnf03 = '+ str(cnf3.value[0]))
    print('cns04 = '+ str(cns4.value[0]))
    print('cnf04 = '+ str(cnf4.value[0]))
    print('cns05 = '+ str(cns5.value[0]))
    print('cnf05 = '+ str(cnf5.value[0]))
    print('cns06 = '+ str(cns6.value[0]))
    print('cnf06 = '+ str(cnf6.value[0]))

plt.figure(1,figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(m.time,c1.value,'b',label='Predicted c1')
plt.plot(m.time,c2.value,'r',label='Predicted c2')
plt.plot(m.time,c3.value,'g',label='Predicted c3')
plt.plot(m.time,c4.value,'b',label='Predicted c4')
plt.plot(m.time,c5.value,'r',label='Predicted c5')
plt.plot(m.time,c6.value,'g',label='Predicted c6')
plt.plot(tm1,mca1,'bo',label='Meas c1')
plt.plot(tm2,mca2,'ro',label='Meas c2')
plt.plot(tm3,mca3,'go',label='Meas c3')
plt.plot(tm4,mca4,'bo',label='Meas c4')
plt.plot(tm5,mca5,'ro',label='Meas c5')
plt.plot(tm6,mca6,'go',label='Meas c6')
plt.xlabel('time (h)')
plt.ylabel('Concentration (mg/L)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    20.3781000000017      sec
 Objective      :    33.5882065490541     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
Final SSE Objective: 33.588206549
Solution
kf = 0.01
ks = 1.0397291201
cnf01 = 0.0
cns01 = 2.7570924931
cns02 = 1.9055347775
cnf02 = 0.0
cns03 = 1.2943612345
cnf03 = 0.58537442202
cns04 = 3.9482253816
cnf04 = 3.0425925867
cns05 = 2.8833138483
cnf05 = 2.3309239496
cns06 = 4.6060598019
cnf06 = 4.5472709683
```

Comment: Thank you, John, for your clear explanation. I still have a doubt regarding the initial conditions. The idea is to fix the initial conditions following this:
`cnf1[0]=cnf01
cnf2[0]=cnf01*0.5
cnf3[0]=cnf01*0.25
cnf4[0]=cnf01
cnf5[0]=cnf01*0.5
cnf6[0]=cnf01*0.25
`
Where is the best place to add this to the code? Should I add in m.Equation? 
My approach was presented in the code I posted above.

Comment: Try using an `FV` with `ic = FV()` to connect to the initial condition with `m.Connection(cnf1,ic,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)`. You can place the constraints on the `FV` called `ic` (initial condition).

Comment: Thank you @Jonh Hedengren for your highlights. I adapted the first code with the m.connection but I am getting 12 warning messages for each cfn* and cns* at p(0).n(1): 

Warning: connection failed
 p(0).n(1).v7 = p(0).n(1).p9
 unable to locate variable
 p(0).n(1).v7
 p(0).n(1).p9

I add m.open_folder()  and I explore some answers in stackoverflow but I am not sure how to avoid this warning message. I posted a new question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66243269/how-to-solve-warning-message-in-gekko-due-to-m-connection