# How to solve warning message in Gekko due to m.connection?

Tags: python, gekko

I am using m.connection to estimate variables initial conditions but I am getting 12 warning messages like:

[image]

Moreover, the APM file shows:

[image]

I am not sure how to solve these messages.

I am following this explanation "If pos1 or pos2 is not None, the associated var must be a GEKKO variable and the position is the (0-indexed) time-discretized index of the variable" to write m.Connection(var1,var2,pos1=None,pos2=None,node1='end',node2='end').
https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html#connections

Thanks in advance.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math as math
import pandas as pd


tm1 = [0, 0.0667,0.5,1,4, 22.61667]
mca1 = [5.68, 3.48, 3.24, 3.36, 2.96, 1.96]

tm2 = [0, 0.08333,0.5,1,4.25 , 22.8167]
mca2 = [5.68, 4.20, 4.04, 4.00, 3.76, 2.88]

tm3 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.33 , 22.9500]
mca3 = [5.68, 4.64, 4.52, 4.56, 4.24, 3.72]

tm4 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.0833 , 23.0833]
mca4 =[18.90,15.4,14.3,15.10,13.50, 10.90]

tm5 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.5, 23.2167]
mca5 =[18.90, 15.5, 16.30, 16, 14.70, 13.00]

tm6 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.6667, 23.3333 ]
mca6 = [18.90, 15.8, 11.70,15.5,12, 9.5 ]

df1=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm1,'x1':mca1})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm2,'x2':mca2})
df3=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm3,'x3':mca3})
df4=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm4,'x4':mca4})
df5=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm5,'x5':mca5})
df6=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm6,'x6':mca6})
df1.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df3.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df4.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df5.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df6.set_index('time',inplace=True)
#simulation time points
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.linspace(0,25,101)})
dfx.set_index('time',inplace=True)
#merge dataframes
dfxx=dfx.join(df1,how='outer')
dfxxx=dfxx.join(df2,how='outer')
dfxxxx=dfxxx.join(df3,how='outer')
dfxxxxx=dfxxxx.join(df4,how='outer')
dfxxxxxx=dfxxxxx.join(df5,how='outer')
df=dfxxxxxx.join(df6,how='outer')
# get True (1) or False (0) for measurement
df['meas1']=(df['x1'].values==df['x1'].values).astype(int)
df['meas2']=(df['x2'].values==df['x2'].values).astype(int)
df['meas3']=(df['x3'].values==df['x3'].values).astype(int)
df['meas4']=(df['x4'].values==df['x4'].values).astype(int)
df['meas5']=(df['x5'].values==df['x5'].values).astype(int)
df['meas6']=(df['x6'].values==df['x6'].values).astype(int)
#replace NaN with zeros
df0=df.fillna(value=0)

m = GEKKO()
m.time = df0.index.values

meas1 = m.Param(df0['meas1'].values)
meas2 = m.Param(df0['meas2'].values)
meas3 = m.Param(df0['meas3'].values)
meas4 = m.Param(df0['meas4'].values)
meas5 = m.Param(df0['meas5'].values)
meas6 = m.Param(df0['meas6'].values)

#adjustable Parameters

kf=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10) 
ks=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10) 

cnf01=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10)  
cns01=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10) 

#constrains
cnf02=m.FV(value=cnf01*0.5,lb=cnf01*0.5, ub=cnf01*0.5)
cns02=m.FV(value=cns01*0.5,lb=cns01*0.5, ub=cns01*0.5)
cnf03=m.FV(value=cnf01*0.25,lb=cnf01*0.25, ub=cnf01*0.25)
cns03=m.FV(value=cns01*0.25,lb=cns01*0.25, ub=cns01*0.25)
cnf04=m.FV(value=cnf01,lb=cnf01, ub=cnf01)
cns04=m.FV(value=cns01,lb=cns01, ub=cns01)
cnf05=m.FV(value=cnf01*0.5,lb=cnf01*0.5, ub=cnf01*0.5)
cns05=m.FV(value=cns01*0.5,lb=cns01*0.5, ub=cns01*0.5)
cnf06=m.FV(value=cnf01*0.25,lb=cnf01*0.25, ub=cnf01*0.25)
cns06=m.FV(value=cns01*0.25,lb=cns01*0.25, ub=cns01*0.25)

#Variables
c1 = m.Var(value=mca1[0])
c2 = m.Var(value=mca2[0])
c3 = m.Var(value=mca3[0])
c4 = m.Var(value=mca4[0])
c5 = m.Var(value=mca5[0])
c6 = m.Var(value=mca6[0])
cm1 = m.Param(df0['x1'].values)
cm2 = m.Param(df0['x2'].values)
cm3 = m.Param(df0['x3'].values)
cm4 = m.Param(df0['x4'].values)
cm5 = m.Param(df0['x5'].values)
cm6 = m.Param(df0['x6'].values)

m.Minimize((meas1*(c1-cm1)**2)+(meas2*(c2-cm2)**2)\
          +(meas3*(c3-cm3)**2)+(meas4*(c4-cm4)**2)\
          +(meas5*(c5-cm5)**2)+(meas6*(c6-cm6)**2))

cnf1=m.Var(value=cnf01,fixed_initial=False)
cns1=m.Var(value=cns01,fixed_initial=False)
cnf2=m.Var(value=cnf02,fixed_initial=False)
cns2=m.Var(value=cns02,fixed_initial=False)
cnf3=m.Var(value=cnf03,fixed_initial=False)
cns3=m.Var(value=cns03,fixed_initial=False)
cnf4=m.Var(value=cnf04,fixed_initial=False)
cns4=m.Var(value=cns04,fixed_initial=False)
cnf5=m.Var(value=cnf05,fixed_initial=False)
cns5=m.Var(value=cns05,fixed_initial=False)
cnf6=m.Var(value=cnf06,fixed_initial=False)
cns6=m.Var(value=cns06,fixed_initial=False)


#Equations
t = m.Param(value=m.time)

m.Connection(cnf1,cnf01,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf2,cnf02,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf3,cnf03,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf4,cnf04,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf5,cnf05,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf6,cnf06,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)

m.Connection(cns1,cns01,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cns2,cns02,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cns3,cns03,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cns4,cns04,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cns5,cns05,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cns6,cns06,pos1=0,pos2=0,node1=1,node2=1)

m.Equation(cnf1.dt()==-kf*c1*cnf1)
m.Equation(cns1.dt()==-ks*c1*cns1)
m.Equation(c1.dt()==cnf1.dt()+cns1.dt())

m.Equation(cnf2.dt()==-kf*c2*cnf2)
m.Equation(cns2.dt()==-ks*c2*cns2)
m.Equation(c2.dt()==cnf2.dt()+cns2.dt())

m.Equation(cnf3.dt()==-kf*c3*cnf3)
m.Equation(cns3.dt()==-ks*c3*cns3)
m.Equation(c3.dt()==cnf3.dt()+cns3.dt())

m.Equation(cnf4.dt()==-kf*c4*cnf4)
m.Equation(cns4.dt()==-ks*c4*cns4)
m.Equation(c4.dt()==cnf4.dt()+cns4.dt())

m.Equation(cnf5.dt()==-kf*c5*cnf5)
m.Equation(cns5.dt()==-ks*c5*cns5)
m.Equation(c5.dt()==cnf5.dt()+cns5.dt())

m.Equation(cnf6.dt()==-kf*c6*cnf6)
m.Equation(cns6.dt()==-ks*c6*cns6)
m.Equation(c6.dt()==cnf6.dt()+cns6.dt())


if True:
    kf.STATUS=1
    ks.STATUS=1
    cnf01.STATUS=1
    cns01.STATUS=1
    cnf02.STATUS=1
    cns02.STATUS=1
    cnf03.STATUS=1
    cns03.STATUS=1
    cnf04.STATUS=1
    cns04.STATUS=1
    cnf05.STATUS=1
    cns05.STATUS=1
    cnf06.STATUS=1
    cns06.STATUS=1

#Options
m.options.SOLVER = 1 #IPOPT solver
m.options.IMODE = 5 #Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation = MHE
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 #absolute error
m.options.NODES = 3 #collocation nodes (2,5)
m.solve(disp=True)
m.open_folder()

print('Final SSE Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))

print('Solution')
print('cnf01 = ' + str(cnf01.value[0]))
print('cns01 = ' + str(cns01.value[0]))
print('kf = ' + str(kf.value[0]))
print('ks = ' + str(ks.value[0]))
print('cns02 = '+ str(cns02.value[0]))
print('cnf02 = '+ str(cnf02.value[0]))
print('cns03 = '+ str(cns03.value[0]))
print('cnf03 = '+ str(cnf03.value[0]))
print('cns04 = '+ str(cns04.value[0]))
print('cnf04 = '+ str(cnf04.value[0]))
print('cns05 = '+ str(cns05.value[0]))
print('cnf05 = '+ str(cnf05.value[0]))
print('cns06 = '+ str(cns06.value[0]))
print('cnf06 = '+ str(cnf06.value[0]))

plt.figure(1,figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(m.time,c1.value,'r',label='Predicted c1')
plt.plot(m.time,c2.value,'y',label='Predicted c2')
plt.plot(m.time,c3.value,'c',label='Predicted c3')
plt.plot(m.time,c4.value,'g',label='Predicted c4')
plt.plot(m.time,c5.value,'b',label='Predicted c5')
plt.plot(m.time,c6.value,'m',label='Predicted c6')
plt.plot(tm1,mca1,'rx',label='Meas c1')
plt.plot(tm2,mca2,'yx',label='Meas c2')
plt.plot(tm3,mca3,'cx',label='Meas c3')
plt.plot(tm4,mca4,'go',label='Meas c4')
plt.plot(tm5,mca5,'bo',label='Meas c5')
plt.plot(tm6,mca6,'mo',label='Meas c6')
plt.xlabel('time (h)')
plt.ylabel('Concentration (mgCl2/L)')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15), ncol=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying node structure has a 1-index instead of a 0-index that is common in Python. Using `pos1=1` and `pos2=1` resolves the warnings.

```py
m.Connection(cnf1,cnf01,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf2,cnf02,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf3,cnf03,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf4,cnf04,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf5,cnf05,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf6,cnf06,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
```

Another issue is that Gekko variables shouldn't generally be used to initialize other values. I recommend setting `x0=1.3` and using that float to initialize the variables. Change `m.Var()` to `m.SV()` to avoid reclassification of `m.Var()` as an `m.FV()` during the connection. The `m.SV()` is a promoted type of variable that is at the same level of precedence as the `m.FV()`. Here is a complete script although the results don't look optimal.

[image: results]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math as math
import pandas as pd

tm1 = [0, 0.0667,0.5,1,4, 22.61667]
mca1 = [5.68, 3.48, 3.24, 3.36, 2.96, 1.96]

tm2 = [0, 0.08333,0.5,1,4.25 , 22.8167]
mca2 = [5.68, 4.20, 4.04, 4.00, 3.76, 2.88]

tm3 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.33 , 22.9500]
mca3 = [5.68, 4.64, 4.52, 4.56, 4.24, 3.72]

tm4 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.0833 , 23.0833]
mca4 =[18.90,15.4,14.3,15.10,13.50, 10.90]

tm5 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.5, 23.2167]
mca5 =[18.90, 15.5, 16.30, 16, 14.70, 13.00]

tm6 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4.6667, 23.3333 ]
mca6 = [18.90, 15.8, 11.70,15.5,12, 9.5 ]

df1=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm1,'x1':mca1})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm2,'x2':mca2})
df3=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm3,'x3':mca3})
df4=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm4,'x4':mca4})
df5=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm5,'x5':mca5})
df6=pd.DataFrame({'time':tm6,'x6':mca6})
df1.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df3.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df4.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df5.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df6.set_index('time',inplace=True)
#simulation time points
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.linspace(0,25,101)})
dfx.set_index('time',inplace=True)
#merge dataframes
dfxx=dfx.join(df1,how='outer')
dfxxx=dfxx.join(df2,how='outer')
dfxxxx=dfxxx.join(df3,how='outer')
dfxxxxx=dfxxxx.join(df4,how='outer')
dfxxxxxx=dfxxxxx.join(df5,how='outer')
df=dfxxxxxx.join(df6,how='outer')
# get True (1) or False (0) for measurement
df['meas1']=(df['x1'].values==df['x1'].values).astype(int)
df['meas2']=(df['x2'].values==df['x2'].values).astype(int)
df['meas3']=(df['x3'].values==df['x3'].values).astype(int)
df['meas4']=(df['x4'].values==df['x4'].values).astype(int)
df['meas5']=(df['x5'].values==df['x5'].values).astype(int)
df['meas6']=(df['x6'].values==df['x6'].values).astype(int)
#replace NaN with zeros
df0=df.fillna(value=0)

m = GEKKO()
m.time = df0.index.values

meas1 = m.Param(df0['meas1'].values)
meas2 = m.Param(df0['meas2'].values)
meas3 = m.Param(df0['meas3'].values)
meas4 = m.Param(df0['meas4'].values)
meas5 = m.Param(df0['meas5'].values)
meas6 = m.Param(df0['meas6'].values)

#adjustable Parameters

kf=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10) 
ks=m.FV(1.3,lb=0.01,ub=10) 

x0 = 1.3
cnf01=m.FV(x0,lb=0.01,ub=10)  
cns01=m.FV(x0,lb=0.01,ub=10) 

#constrains
cnf02=m.FV(value=x0*0.5,lb=x0*0.5, ub=x0*0.5)
cns02=m.FV(value=x0*0.5,lb=x0*0.5, ub=x0*0.5)
cnf03=m.FV(value=x0*0.25,lb=x0*0.25, ub=x0*0.25)
cns03=m.FV(value=x0*0.25,lb=x0*0.25, ub=x0*0.25)
cnf04=m.FV(value=x0,lb=x0, ub=x0)
cns04=m.FV(value=x0,lb=x0, ub=x0)
cnf05=m.FV(value=x0*0.5,lb=x0*0.5, ub=x0*0.5)
cns05=m.FV(value=x0*0.5,lb=x0*0.5, ub=x0*0.5)
cnf06=m.FV(value=x0*0.25,lb=x0*0.25, ub=x0*0.25)
cns06=m.FV(value=x0*0.25,lb=x0*0.25, ub=x0*0.25)

#Variables
c1 = m.SV(value=mca1[0])
c2 = m.SV(value=mca2[0])
c3 = m.SV(value=mca3[0])
c4 = m.SV(value=mca4[0])
c5 = m.SV(value=mca5[0])
c6 = m.SV(value=mca6[0])
cm1 = m.Param(df0['x1'].values)
cm2 = m.Param(df0['x2'].values)
cm3 = m.Param(df0['x3'].values)
cm4 = m.Param(df0['x4'].values)
cm5 = m.Param(df0['x5'].values)
cm6 = m.Param(df0['x6'].values)

m.Minimize((meas1*(c1-cm1)**2)+(meas2*(c2-cm2)**2)\
          +(meas3*(c3-cm3)**2)+(meas4*(c4-cm4)**2)\
          +(meas5*(c5-cm5)**2)+(meas6*(c6-cm6)**2))

cnf1=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)
cns1=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)
cnf2=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)
cns2=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)
cnf3=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)
cns3=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)
cnf4=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)
cns4=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)
cnf5=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)
cns5=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)
cnf6=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)
cns6=m.SV(value=x0,fixed_initial=False)

#Equations
t = m.Param(value=m.time)

m.Connection(cnf1,cnf01,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf2,cnf02,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf3,cnf03,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf4,cnf04,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf5,cnf05,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cnf6,cnf06,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)

m.Connection(cns1,cns01,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cns2,cns02,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cns3,cns03,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cns4,cns04,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cns5,cns05,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
m.Connection(cns6,cns06,pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)

m.Equation(cnf1.dt()==-kf*c1*cnf1)
m.Equation(cns1.dt()==-ks*c1*cns1)
m.Equation(c1.dt()==cnf1.dt()+cns1.dt())

m.Equation(cnf2.dt()==-kf*c2*cnf2)
m.Equation(cns2.dt()==-ks*c2*cns2)
m.Equation(c2.dt()==cnf2.dt()+cns2.dt())

m.Equation(cnf3.dt()==-kf*c3*cnf3)
m.Equation(cns3.dt()==-ks*c3*cns3)
m.Equation(c3.dt()==cnf3.dt()+cns3.dt())

m.Equation(cnf4.dt()==-kf*c4*cnf4)
m.Equation(cns4.dt()==-ks*c4*cns4)
m.Equation(c4.dt()==cnf4.dt()+cns4.dt())

m.Equation(cnf5.dt()==-kf*c5*cnf5)
m.Equation(cns5.dt()==-ks*c5*cns5)
m.Equation(c5.dt()==cnf5.dt()+cns5.dt())

m.Equation(cnf6.dt()==-kf*c6*cnf6)
m.Equation(cns6.dt()==-ks*c6*cns6)
m.Equation(c6.dt()==cnf6.dt()+cns6.dt())

#Options
m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT solver
m.options.IMODE = 5   # Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation = MHE
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 # Squared error
m.options.NODES = 3   # Collocation nodes (2,5)

if True:
    kf.STATUS=1
    ks.STATUS=1
    cnf01.STATUS=1
    cns01.STATUS=1
    cnf02.STATUS=1
    cns02.STATUS=1
    cnf03.STATUS=1
    cns03.STATUS=1
    cnf04.STATUS=1
    cns04.STATUS=1
    cnf05.STATUS=1
    cns05.STATUS=1
    cnf06.STATUS=1
    cns06.STATUS=1

m.options.TIME_SHIFT = 0
try:
    m.solve(disp=True)
except:
    print("don't stop when not finding cnf01...cnf06")

#m.open_folder()

print('Final SSE Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))

print('Solution')
print('cnf01 = ' + str(cnf1.value[0]))
print('cns01 = ' + str(cns1.value[0]))
print('kf = ' + str(kf.value[0]))
print('ks = ' + str(ks.value[0]))
print('cns02 = '+ str(cns2.value[0]))
print('cnf02 = '+ str(cnf2.value[0]))
print('cns03 = '+ str(cns3.value[0]))
print('cnf03 = '+ str(cnf3.value[0]))
print('cns04 = '+ str(cns4.value[0]))
print('cnf04 = '+ str(cnf4.value[0]))
print('cns05 = '+ str(cns5.value[0]))
print('cnf05 = '+ str(cnf5.value[0]))
print('cns06 = '+ str(cns6.value[0]))
print('cnf06 = '+ str(cnf6.value[0]))

plt.figure(1,figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(m.time,c1.value,'r',label='Predicted c1')
plt.plot(m.time,c2.value,'y',label='Predicted c2')
plt.plot(m.time,c3.value,'c',label='Predicted c3')
plt.plot(m.time,c4.value,'g',label='Predicted c4')
plt.plot(m.time,c5.value,'b',label='Predicted c5')
plt.plot(m.time,c6.value,'m',label='Predicted c6')
plt.plot(tm1,mca1,'rx',label='Meas c1')
plt.plot(tm2,mca2,'yx',label='Meas c2')
plt.plot(tm3,mca3,'cx',label='Meas c3')
plt.plot(tm4,mca4,'go',label='Meas c4')
plt.plot(tm5,mca5,'bo',label='Meas c5')
plt.plot(tm6,mca6,'mo',label='Meas c6')
plt.xlabel('time (h)')
plt.ylabel('Concentration (mgCl2/L)')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15), ncol=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you John for your support. I followed your advice about shortening the model using arrays in a mechanistic model. I am trying to use m.connection strategy. I am not getting a good result. I hope you can help me again. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738794/how-to-apply-m-connection-from-gekko-using-arrays)