# Parameters estimation regarding constraints for initial values are not working with m.connection or fixed_initial, any suggestion on that?

Tags: gekko

Following the suggestion from [Rate coefficients and initial concentration estimation using gekko - advice about model structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990332/rate-coefficients-and-initial-concentration-estimation-using-gekko-advice-abou)
I adapted the code for two data sets and it ran (I am using COLDSTART=2).

[image]

However, I still have these doubts and it would be great to have some suggestions:

1. I want to estimate kdoc1 and kdoc2 and the initial values (t=0) of `DOC1` and `DOC2` which are `DOC10` and `DOC20`, regarding `DOC10[1] = DOC10[0]*0.5` and `DOC20[1] = DOC20[0]*0.5`. I am expecting to get the relation for `t=0` and after that `DOC10` and `DOC20` will decay, but it is not happening, values are keeping constant.
2. I am not using `m.connection` because I got this error:

```
p13 not found in results file
p14 not found in results file
p15 not found in results file
p16 not found in results file
```

3. and neither using `fixed_initial =False` because it gives infeasibilities
4. Another issue is that I need to comment the variables initialization to achieve a result.
5. The estimated values are equal to the initial values proposed. It seems the program is not fitting and not giving an estimation value.

Here is the code:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math as math
import pandas as pd

#data set 1
t_data1 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4,22.61667]
x_data1 = [0,4.91e-5,4.57e-5,4.74e-5,4.17e-5,2.76e-5]
x_data1mgl = [0,3.48,3.24,3.36,2.96,1.96]

#data set 2
t_data2 = [0,0.08333,0.5,1,4,22.8167]
x_data2 = [0,5.92e-5,5.7e-5,5.64e-5,5.30e-5,4.6e-5]
x_data2mgl = [0,4.2,4.04,4,3.76,2.88]
      
#combine data and time in the same dataframe
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'time':t_data1,'x1':x_data1})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'time':t_data2,'x2':x_data2})
data1.set_index('time', inplace=True)
data2.set_index('time', inplace=True)


# merge dataframes
data = data1.join(data4, how='outer')

# simulation time points
dftp = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.linspace(0,25,51)})
dftp.set_index('time', inplace=True)

# merge dataframes
df = data.join(dftp,how='outer')

# get True (1) or False (0) for measurement
#df['meas'] = (df['x'].values==df['x'].values).astype(int)
z1 = (df['x1']==df['x1']).astype(int)
z2 = (df['x2']==df['x2']).astype(int)


# replace NaN with zeros
df0 = df.fillna(value=0)

#Estimator Model
m = GEKKO()#remote=True)
#m = GEKKO(remote=False) # remote=False to produce local folder with results

m.time = df.index.values

# measurements - Gekko arrays to store measured data
xm = m.Array(m.Param,2)
xm[0].value = df0['x1'].values
xm[1].value = df0['x2'].values

hocl_init_val=m.Array(m.Param,2)
hocl_init_val[0].value= 8.01e-5
hocl_init_val[1].value= 8.01e-5

nh3_init_val=m.Array(m.Param,2)
nh3_init_val[0].value= 1.37e-3 
nh3_init_val[1].value= 6.82e-4

h_init_val=m.Array(m.Param,2)
h_init_val[0].value= 6.31e-8 
h_init_val[1].value= 2e-8

#h2co3_init_val=m.Array(m.Param,2)
#h2co3_init_val[0].value= 5.39e-4
#h2co3_init_val[1].value= 1.88e-4

hco3_init_val=m.Array(m.Param,2)
hco3_init_val[0].value= 3.46e-3
hco3_init_val[1].value= 3.80e-3

#co32_init_val=m.Array(m.Param,2)
#co32_init_val[0].value= 2.16e-6
#co32_init_val[1].value= 7.5e-6

alk_init_val=m.Array(m.Param,2)
alk_init_val[0].value= 3.46e-3
alk_init_val[1].value= 3.82e-3

#adjustable parameters

x1=3.1684e-5
x2=3.1308e-5

DOC10=m.Array(m.FV,2)
DOC10[0].value= x1
DOC10[1].value= x1*0.5

DOC20=m.Array(m.FV,2)
DOC20[0].value= x2
DOC20[1].value= x2*0.5


kdoc1 = m.FV(1e6,lb=0.01,ub=1e7) #m.Const(1.2334e6)
kdoc2 = m.FV(1e9,lb=0.01,ub=1e10) #m.Const(3.8809e9)
#DOC10 = m.FV(1e-5,lb=1e-7,ub=1e-2)
#DOC20 = m.FV(1e-5,lb=1e-7,ub=1e-2)


#variables initialization
# hocl=m.Array(m.Var,2,lb=0,ub=1e-4)
# nh3=m.Array(m.Var,2,lb=0,ub=1.5e-4)
# nh2cl=m.Array(m.Var,2,lb=0,ub=1e-4)
# C2m=m.Array(m.Var,2)
# cC2=m.Array(m.Var,2)
# nhcl2=m.Array(m.Var,2)
# h=m.Array(m.Param,2)
# #oh=m.Array(m.Var,2)
# I=m.Array(m.Var,2)
# ocl=m.Array(m.Var,2)
# nh4=m.Array(m.Var,2)
# #h2co3=m.Array(m.Var,2)
# hco3=m.Array(m.Var,2)
# #co32=m.Array(m.Var,2)
# alk=m.Array(m.Var,2)
# DOC1=m.Array(m.SV,2)
# DOC2=m.Array(m.SV,2)

#to support intermediate
co32=[None]*2
h2co3=[None]*2

oh=[None]*2

r1=[None]*2
r2=[None]*2
r3=[None]*2
r4=[None]*2
r5=[None]*2
r6=[None]*2
r7=[None]*2
r8=[None]*2
r9=[None]*2
r10=[None]*2
r11=[None]*2
r12=[None]*2
r13=[None]*2
r14=[None]*2
r15=[None]*2
r16=[None]*2

#Define GEKKO variables that determine if time 
#point contains data to be used in regression
zm = m.Array(m.Param,2)
zm[0].value=z1
zm[1].value=z2

# fit to measurement
x=m.Array(m.Param,2) 
x[0].value=x_data1[0]
x[1].value=x_data4[0]

k5=m.Array(m.Var,2)

k1 = m.Const(1.5e10)
k2 = m.Const(7.6e-2)
k3 = m.Const(1e6)
k4 = m.Const(2.3e-3)
k6 = m.Const(2.2e8)
k7 = m.Const(4e5)
k8 = m.Const(1e8)
k9 = m.Const(3e7)
k10 = m.Const(55)
k11 = m.Const(3.16e-8*1e10)
k12 = m.Const(1e10)
k13 = m.Const(5.01e-10*1e10)
k14 = m.Const(1e10)

for i in range(2):

    hocl[i] = m.Var(value=hocl_init_val[i],lb=0,ub=1e-2)
    nh3[i] = m.Var(value=nh3_init_val[i],lb=0,ub=1.5e-3)
    nh2cl[i] = m.Var(value=x[i],lb=0,ub=3e-4)
    
    C2m[i] = m.Param(xm[i],lb=0)
    meas = m.Param(zm[i])
    m.Minimize(meas*((nh2cl[i]-C2m[i]))**2)
    
    nhcl2[i] = m.Var(value=0)
    
    h[i] = m.Param(value=h_init_val[i])
    
    I[i] = m.Var(value=0)
    ocl[i]= m.Var(value=0)
    nh4[i] = m.Var(value=0)
    #h2co3[i] = m.Var(value=h2co3_init_val[i])
    hco3[i] = m.Var(value=hco3_init_val[i])
    #co32[i] = m.Var(value=co32_init_val[i])
    alk[i] = m.Var(value=alk_init_val[i])
    DOC1[i] = m.SV(value=DOC10[i])#,fixed_initial=False)
    DOC2[i] = m.SV(value=DOC20[i])#,fixed_initial=False)
    cC2[i] = m.Var(value=0)
    
    oh[i] = m.Intermediate(1e-14/h_init_val[i])

    r1[i] = m.Intermediate(k1 * hocl[i] * nh3[i])
    r2[i] = m.Intermediate(k2 * nh2cl[i])
    r3[i] = m.Intermediate(k3 * hocl[i] * nh2cl[i])
    r4[i] = m.Intermediate(k4 * nh3[i])
    r5[i] = m.Intermediate(k5[i] * nh2cl[i] * nh2cl[i])
    r6[i] = m.Intermediate(k6 * nhcl2[i] * nh3[i]* h[i])
    r7[i] = m.Intermediate(k7 * nhcl2[i] * oh[i])
    r8[i] = m.Intermediate(k8 * I[i] * nhcl2[i])
    r9[i] = m.Intermediate(k9 * I[i] * nh2cl[i])
    r10[i] = m.Intermediate(k10 * nh2cl[i] * nhcl2[i])
    
    r11[i] = m.Intermediate(k11*hocl[i])
    r12[i] = m.Intermediate(k12*h[i]*ocl[i])
    r13[i] = m.Intermediate(k13*nh4[i])
    r14[i] = m.Intermediate(k14*h[i]*nh3[i])
    
    r15[i] = m.Intermediate(kdoc1*DOC1[i]*nh2cl[i])
    r16[i] = m.Intermediate(kdoc2*DOC2[i]*hocl[i])

    co32[i] = m.Intermediate(5.01e-11*hco3[i]/h[i])
    h2co3[i] = m.Intermediate(hco3[i]*h[i]/5.01e-7)
    
    t = m.Param(value=m.time)
    m.Equation(hocl[i].dt()== -r1[i] + r2[i] - r3[i] + r4[i] + r8[i] - r11[i] + r12[i] - r16[i])
    m.Equation(nh3[i].dt()== -r1[i] + r2[i] + r5[i] - r6[i] + r13[i] - r14[i])# + r11[i])
    m.Equation(nh2cl[i].dt()== r1[i] - r2[i] - r3[i] + r4[i] - r5[i] + r6[i] - r9[i] - r10[i] - r15[i])
    m.Equation(nhcl2[i].dt()== r3[i] - r4[i] + r5[i] - r6[i] - r7[i] - r8[i] - r10[i])
    #m.Equation(h[i].dt()== 0)
    #m.Equation(oh[i] == 1e-14/h[i])
    m.Equation(I[i].dt()== r7[i] - r8[i] - r9[i])
    #m.Equation(ocl[i] == (3.16e-8*hocl[i])/h[i])
    #m.Equation(nh4[i] == nh3[i]*h[i]/5.01e-10)
    m.Equation(ocl[i].dt()==r11[i]-r12[i])
    m.Equation(nh4[i].dt()==-r13[i]+r14[i])
    #m.Equation(co32[i] == (5.01e-11*hco3[i])/h[i])
    #m.Equation(h2co3[i] == (hco3[i])*h[i]/5.01e-7)
    m.Equation(hco3[i] == alk[i] - 2*5.01e-11*hco3[i]/h[i] - oh[i] + h[i])
    m.Equation(alk[i].dt()== 0)
    
    m.Equation(DOC1[i].dt()== -r15[i])
    m.Equation(DOC2[i].dt()== -r16[i])
    
    m.Equation(cC2[i] == 51500*nh2cl[i])
    
    m.Equation(k5[i] == 2.5e7*h[i]+4e4*(hco3[i]*h[i]/5.01e-7)+800*hco3[i])

    #m.Connection(DOC1[i],DOC10[i],pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
    #m.Connection(DOC2[i],DOC20[i],pos1=1,pos2=1,node1=1,node2=1)
    
#Application options
m.options.SOLVER = 3 #IPOPT solver
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 #absolute error
#m.options.NODES = 3 #collocation nodes (2,5)
#m.options.RTOL = 1E-6

if True:
    kdoc1.STATUS=1
    kdoc2.STATUS=1
    DOC10[i].STATUS=1
    DOC20[i].STATUS=1

#m.options.IMODE = 7
#m.options.RTOL = 1E-6
#m.solve(dis=True)

m.options.IMODE = 5 #Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation = MHE
m.options.COLDSTART=2
m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0

m.open_folder()
m.solve(disp=True)

print('Final SSE Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))

print('Solution')
print('kdoc1 = ' + str(kdoc1.value[0]))
print('kdoc2 = ' + str(kdoc2.value[0]))
print('DOC10_w1 = ' + str(DOC10[0].value[0]))
print('DOC20_w1 = ' + str(DOC20[0].value[0]))
print('DOC10_w2 = ' + str(DOC10[1].value[1]))
print('DOC20_w2 = ' + str(DOC20[1].value[1]))

plt.figure(1,figsize=(8,5))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,nh2cl[0],'b.--',label='Predicted 1')
plt.plot(m.time,nh2cl[1],'r.--',label='Predicted 2')

plt.plot(t_data1,x_data1,'bx',label='Meas 1')
plt.plot(t_data2,x_data2,'rx',label='Meas 2')
#plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylabel('mol/L')
plt.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.45, 0.5), ncol=2) #shadow=True,

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,cC2[0].value,'b',label ='C2_M1')
plt.plot(m.time,cC2[1].value,'r',label ='C2_M2')
plt.plot(t_data1,x_data1mgl,'bx',label='Meas 1')
plt.plot(t_data2,x_data2mgl,'rx',label='Meas 2')

plt.ylabel('mg Cl2/L')
plt.xlabel('time (h)')
plt.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.4, 0.5),  ncol=2) #shadow=True,


plt.figure(2,figsize=(12,8))
plt.subplot(4,3,1)
plt.plot(m.time,hocl[i].value,label ='hocl')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,2)
plt.plot(m.time,nh3[i].value,label ='nh3')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,3)
plt.plot(m.time,nhcl2[i].value,label ='nhcl2')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,4)
plt.plot(m.time,h[i].value,label ='h')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,5)
plt.plot(m.time,oh[i].value,label ='oh')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,6)
plt.plot(m.time,I[i].value,label ='I')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,7)
plt.plot(m.time,ocl[i].value,label ='ocl')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,8)
plt.plot(m.time,nh4[i].value,label ='nh4')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4,3,9)
plt.plot(m.time,h2co3[i].value,label ='h2co3')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.subplot(4,3,10)
plt.plot(m.time,hco3[i].value,label ='hco3')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.subplot(4,3,11)
plt.plot(m.time,co32[i].value,label ='co32')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.subplot(4,3,12)
plt.plot(m.time,alk[i].value,label ='alk')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time (h)')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ideas:

1. Try a range of fixed initial conditions `DOC10` and `DOC20` and then re-optimize with every combination. This can be [parallelized with multithreading](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/ParallelComputing) so that multiple optimization problems run simultaneously to speed up the solution.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

# Optimize at mesh points
x = np.arange(20.0, 30.0, 2.0)
y = np.arange(30.0, 50.0, 4.0)
amg, bmg = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Initialize results array
obj = np.empty_like(amg)

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
objective = float('NaN')

a,b = m.Array(m.FV,2)

# model variables, equations, objective
x1 = m.Var(1,lb=1,ub=5)
x2 = m.Var(5,lb=1,ub=5)
x3 = m.Var(5,lb=1,ub=5)
x4 = m.Var(1,lb=1,ub=5)
m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=a)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==b)
m.Minimize(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3)
m.options.SOLVER = 1 # APOPT solver

# Calculate obj at all meshgrid points
for i in range(amg.shape[0]):
    for j in range(bmg.shape[1]):
        a.MEAS = amg[i,j]
        b.MEAS = bmg[i,j]

        m.solve(disp=False)

        obj[i,j] = m.options.OBJFCNVAL
        print(amg[i,j],bmg[i,j],obj[i,j])

# plot 3D figure of results
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(amg, bmg, obj, \
       rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, \
       vmin = 10, vmax = 25, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_xlabel('a')
ax.set_ylabel('b')
ax.set_zlabel('obj')
plt.show()
```

[image: range of optimization values]

2. If the optimizer needs to chose the values, another option is to write out the discretization equations with orthogonal collocation on finite elements. This gives much more control with `IMODE=3` because all of the equations and variables are individually defined for each time point. Here is a Gekko model with `IMODE=4`:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False) # create GEKKO model
y = m.Var(5.0,name='y') # create GEKKO variable
m.Equation(y.dt()==-y)  # create GEKKO equation
m.time = [0,1,2,3]      # time points
m.options.IMODE = 4     # simulation mode
m.options.NODES = 4     # set NODES=4
m.options.CSV_WRITE=2   # write results_all.json
                        #   with internal nodes
m.solve(disp=False)     # solve
```

and the equivalent model with `IMODE=3`:

```py
import numpy as np
N = np.array([[0.436,-0.281, 0.121], \
              [0.614, 0.064, 0.0461], \
              [0.603, 0.230, 0.167]])

time = np.array([0.0, \
                 0.5-np.sqrt(5)/10.0, \
                 0.5+np.sqrt(5)/10.0, \
                 1.0])

from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
y0 = 5
y  = m.Array(m.Var,3,value=0)
dy = m.Array(m.Var,3,value=0)

Ndy = np.dot(N,dy)
m.Equations([Ndy[i]==(y[i]-y0) for i in range(3)])
m.Equations([dy[i]+y[i]==0 for i in range(3)])
m.solve(disp=False)
print(y)
```

This would cause a major rewrite of the model but may be necessary if more control is needed. Additional information on [Orthogonal Collocation on Finite Elements](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/OrthogonalCollocation) is in the Dynamic Optimization course.